# Utility to extract dates from filenames in Bash?

Tags: bash, sed

How can I get `$YEAR`, `$MONTH`, and `$DAY` variables from the following filenames:

```
201601010557 - Development Database.bak
Screen Shot 2017-01-11 at 10.42.14 PM
SIRIUS Internet Radio - Howard 100 20101220 0600.mp3
Howard Stern Show - 20160413.mp3
```

I'm trying to organize files by the date within the name.  However, I'm having difficulty understanding the `sed` and `grep` commands.  The files contain dates in three different formats.

I've found one example that works well on files with the hyphenated date, but it uses `#` placeholders for `sed` (which is causing my brain to hurt).  I would much rather have a `$YEAR`, `$MONTH`, and `$DAY` variable so I can understand it better and tweak the function to my liking (ie `order-by-month` or `order-by-year`).

```
org-by-date(){
    ls -A1 | grep -E '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}' | while read -r line; do
        DNAME="$(echo $line | grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}' | sed 's#-#/#g')"
        mkdir -p "./$DNAME"
        mv "$line" "./$DNAME/"
    done
}
```

Is there an easier way to get the date variables?  For example:

```
order-by-date(){
    ls -A1 | grep -E '( ... magic pattern here ... )' | while read -r line; do
        YEAR="$(echo $line....)
        MONTH="$(echo $line....)
        DAY="$(echo $line....)

        # ... and in a perfect world, get times IF they exist...
        HOUR="$(echo $line....)
        MINUTE="$(echo $line....)
        SECOND="$(echo $line....)
    done
}
```

Comment: Please add sample output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus: done (thanks in advance)

Comment: @G. Deward Are you open for something involving awk?

Comment: @LarsFischer Honestly, I'm too much of a noob to say "yes" or "no" either way.  As long as it is verbose enough for a noob to understand AND can deal with the different formats, then I'd be grateful.

Comment: Note that this question has several duplicates with alternative answers and sometimes slightly different boundary conditions; see the "Linked" questions on the right (or below, on the mobile site).

Answer (score 5):

With a regex and [Parameter Expansion](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
for i in *; do
  [[ $i =~ [0-9]{8}|[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} ]]
  x="${BASH_REMATCH[0]//-/}"
  y="${x:0:4}"
  m="${x:4:2}"
  d="${x:6:2}"
  echo "$y $m $d"
done | sort -n
```

Output:

```
2010 12 20
2016 01 01
2016 04 13
2017 01 11
```

Comment: I understand the "or" logic, but what happens to `y`, `m`, `d`, etc. if the file name was "Cool Filename 20161231.mp3" or "Cooler Filename 20161231 0600.png"?

Comment: Output would be in both cases `2016 12 31`.

Comment: Doesn't `${x:4:2}` assign by string length and position?  If so, wouldn't it be different when hyphens are present?

Comment: It is first position and string length. Possible hyphens are replaced by nothing: `x="${BASH_REMATCH[0]//-/}"`

Comment: `BASH_REMATCH` I didnt know that. Thanks for this insightful example.