# How to extract only a chunk of digits from a filename in Bash?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

In another question, user @Cyrus explained [how to extract the dates from a filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41706054/utility-to-extract-dates-from-filenames-in-bash).  I now have to account for files where there may be other numerical garbage in the file name.

Some of my files have prefixes.  For example:

```
01 - Camera 03 - 20161231.mp4
02 - Camera 03 - 20161231.mp4
03 - Camera 03 - 20161231.mp4
```

His original answer (below) shows how to do it assuming the filename does not have this garbage:

```
for i in *; do
  [[ $i =~ [0-9]{8}|[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} ]]
  x="${BASH_REMATCH[0]//-/}"
  y="${x:0:4}"
  m="${x:4:2}"
  d="${x:6:2}"
  echo "$y $m $d"
done | sort -n
```

Is there a way to extract *only* the chunk of the file name that fits a certain pattern?  For example:

```
yyyyMMdd
yyyyMMddHHmmss
yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss
```

As with the other question, my goal is to get the values from the DATE portion while ignoring the garbage (prefix, non-date numerics, etc.):

Output:

```
2010 12 20
2016 01 01
2016 04 13
2017 01 11
2017 01 17 16 02 30
```

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Please add sample output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Couldn't you first *qualify* the string as fitting a pattern and then *split* the parts?  For example `parts=$(echo $file | tr " " "\n")`?

Comment: There are a number of pattern matching modifiers in bash parameter expansion. Have you looked at the section of the manual that describes them? https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Comment: You've tagged this question [tag:bash], [tag:awk] and [tag:sed], but the only code included is from the response to another question. Where is the code you'd like help with? Or are you just looking for handouts? Also, I absolutely do not see how the dates in the "output" you list map to the dates in the example input at the top of your question.

Comment: `sed -n -e 's/^.*\([0-9]{4}\)\([0-9]{2}\)\([0-9]{2}\).*$/\1 \2 \3/p` Takes any line with an 8 digit string and turns it into `yyyy mm dd`.  It's fairly trivial sed.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in a script :

```
#!/bin/bash -ue

match_timestamp()
{
local 
local -r line="$1"

[[ "$line" =~ $TIMESTAMP_PATTERN ]] || return # Return if non-matching

# We have a match
echo "Match found"
echo "   Line received : $line"
echo "       Timestamp : "

YR="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
MO="${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
DM="${BASH_REMATCH[6]}"
HH="${BASH_REMATCH[8]}"
MM="${BASH_REMATCH[10]}"
SS="${BASH_REMATCH[12]}"

if
  [[ "$YR" ]] && [[ "$MO" ]] && [[ "$DM" ]]
then
  # The date is available, we print it
  echo -n "  $YR-$MO-$DM"
  if
    [[ "$HH" ]] && [[ "$MM" ]]
  then
    # The time is available, we print it
    echo -n " $HH:$MM"
    if
      [[ "$SS" ]]
    then
      # Seconds are available, we print that too
      echo -n ":$SS"
    fi
  fi
  echo
fi

}

main()
{

# Constants declared here once, reused in other function (regex patterns)
local -r PYR="([12][0-9][0-9][0-9])"
local -r PMO="([01][0-9])"
local -r PDM="([1-9]|[0-3][0-9])"
local -r PHH="([0-2][0-9])?"
local -r PMM="([0-5][0-9])?"
local -r PSS="([0-5][0-9])?"

# Pattern for separator between fields (including no separator at all)
local -r SP="([^0-9a-zA-Z]*)"
# Pattern for anything but a digit
local -r NAD="[^0-9]"
# Big pattern that matches timestamps with flexibility
local -r TIMESTAMP_PATTERN="(^|$NAD)$PYR$SP$PMO$SP$PDM$SP$PHH$SP$PMM$SP$PSS($NAD|$)"

local line

if
  [[ -t 0 ]]
then
  for line in "$@"
  do
    match_timestamp "$line"
  done 
else
  while IFS= read -r line
  do
    match_timestamp "$line"
  done
fi
}

main "$@"
```

This script can receive strings (filenames or otherwise) on standard input (one per line) or be provided with strings as arguments ; if standard input is not connected to a terminal, the first mode applies, otherwise the second.

As proposed, it will only match with 4-digit years, 2-digit months, days-of-month, hours, minutes and seconds.  However, anything after day of month can be omitted and it will still match with the part found (with that single big regex made out of smaller concatenated regexes).  Added flexibility could be added by tweaking the regexes.  You can use separators or not (thanks to the separator regex).

The patterns are not bullet-proof (e.g. 25 will be accepted for hours, and February 30 will be accepted), but for basic purposes, it should be useful.

Seeing how nice it turned out, that is one I am going to keep!